# Are there any good blogs or articles on the business of indie games?

Tags: business

Interested in both successes and failures (and semi-successes).

Maybe this might be better at OnStartups but I think the game market is quite a bit different than the business market that's prevalent there (i.e. selling something that's fun instead of selling something that's useful)

Comment: Since there is no clear answer and this question will inevitably end up in list form, I converted this to community wiki.

Comment: @Ricket thanks, I meant to ask a mod to do that but I got distracted.

Answer (score 3):

[Cliffski's Blog](http://positech.co.uk/cliffsblog/) is really great, he goes into all aspects of indie developement. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Struct.ca](http://struct.ca/) (Matt Rix). He was really successful with his [Trainyard](http://www.trainyard.ca/) game and shared lots of interesting sales and marketing related facts on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

http://gamesfromwithin.com/
Noel Llopis' blog on iPhone and indie gamedev is top notch in every aspect.

http://gbgames.com/blog/
Reflects a lot on the technical and financial issues associated with someone's first indie title.

I can highly recommend the both of them.

Answer (score 1):

- [Tales of the Rampant Coyote](http://rampantgames.com/blog/): more design/development than business, but does at times talk about the business/economic aspects of game development.
- [The Bottom Feeder](http://jeff-vogel.blogspot.com/)
- [Lost Garden](http://www.lostgarden.com/)
- [Make it big in Games](http://makeitbigingames.com/)
- [Video Games Business and Marketing](http://vgbm.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Not a blog, but a subreddit: [Marveloper](http://www.reddit.com/r/Marveloper/)